# How to move a column to another table, replacing a FK?

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables, one is a parent table to the other two. I want to separate out a column, moving it into the children tables based on the FK. This needs to be accomplished in SQL (no studio shortcuts).

I have 2 tables like these:

```
TABLE A:
internalID  |  id  | otherdata
============+======+===========
  myid      |   1  | ...
------------+------+-----------
  my2ndid   |   2  | ...
------------+------+-----------
  1234      |   3  | ...
------------+------+-----------
  5678      |   4  | ...

TABLE B:
internalID  |  FK_toTableA  | otherdata
============+===============+===========
  NULL      |       1       | ...
------------+---------------+-----------
  NULL      |       2       | ...

TABLE C:
internalID  |  FK_toTableA  | otherdata
============+===============+===========
  NULL      |       3       | ...
------------+---------------+-----------
  NULL      |       4       | ...
```

I'd like to move or copy `internalID` from `TABLE A` to `TABLE B` & `TABLE C` - based on the FK relationship, then delete the internalID column from `TABLE A`.

The resulting tables should look like this:

```
TABLE A:
  id  | otherdata
======+===========
   1  | ...
------+-----------
   2  | ...
------+-----------
   3  | ...
------+-----------
   4  | ...

TABLE B:
internalID  |  FK_toTableA  | otherdata
============+===============+===========
  myid      |       1       | ...
------------+---------------+-----------
  my2ndid   |       2       | ...

TABLE C:
internalID  |  FK_toTableA  | otherdata
============+===============+===========
  1234      |       3       | ...
------------+---------------+-----------
  5678      |       4       | ...
```

SQL version: 13.0.4001.0

Comment: You just need an update statement. What have you tried?

Comment: This has been asked and answered literally thousands of times. Here is one such example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple use `update` statement :

```
update b
    set b.internalID  = a.internalID 
from b inner join
     a
     on a.id = b.FK_toTableA;
```

After then you can drop your column `internalId` from table `a`.

```
alter table a
    drop column internalId;
```

Comment: So this runs in a migration task, and I'm getting an error after it has already completed, and try to run it again. I have it wrapped in an IF to prevent this error, dut it doesn't seem to work: `IF EXISTS(...a.internalID...)...` it seems like it's ignoring that IF both in the app and Sever Studio... Any ideas?

Comment: I went ahead and made a post for that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932943/if-does-not-prevent-error-but-only-if-it-has-already-executed

Answer (score 1):

```
Update TableB
set internalId = a.InternalId
from TableA a
where tableB.FK_toTableA = a.Id;

Update TableC
set internalId = a.InternalId
from TableA a
where tableC.FK_toTableA = a.Id;

alter table tableA drop column internalId;
```