# 'IF' does not prevent error, but only if it has already executed

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to move a column from one table to another ([here's the post for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898001/how-to-move-a-column-to-another-table-replacing-a-fk)),

However this runs as a task, and may run after it has already completed so I need a clause that prevents the logic from running again. I thought I could achieve this with an IF:

```
IF EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Table_A')
        AND name = 'internalID'
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table_B
        SET b.internalID = a.internal_ID
    FROM Table_B b INNER JOIN
            Table_A a
            ON a.id = b.FK_toTableA;

    ALTER TABLE Table_A DROP COLUMN internalID;
END
```

However, I get an error at

```
SET b.internalID = a.internal_ID
```

The error is:

> Invalid column name 'internalID'.

***But Only If*** `a.internalID` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: It should be `WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(Table_A)
        AND name = 'internalID'` <- quotes missing

Comment: Yes, you're getting a *compilation* error. You cannot fix compilation errors with *runtime* logic. You need to force the later code to not be compiled until you know it's valid, by e.g. using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `EXEC sp_executesql`:

```
IF EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Table_A')
        AND name = 'internalID'
)
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE Table_B
            SET b.internalID = a.internal_ID
        FROM Table_B b INNER JOIN
                Table_A a
                ON a.id = b.FK_toTableA';

    ALTER TABLE Table_A DROP COLUMN internalID;
END
```

I guess because SQL Server complies the whole thing - even that stuff bypassed via conditional logic - before running the script.

Here's [a good article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/exec-and-sp_executesql-how-are-they-different/) about what `sql_executesql` does, compared to EXEC, but it basically boils down to more injection prevention.

Comment: `sql_execsql` doesn't exist on any version, so far as I'm aware, so if that's what you put in, it was right to complain. `sp_executesql` on the other hand is well documented and exists on all versions of SQL Server you're likely to run into these days.